# Ionic 3 background colors

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Is there a built-in way to set background color on `<ion-content>` in Ionic 3?

In Ionic 1, we could set the color scheme for `<ion-content>` using classes like `content-stable`. In newer versions of Ionic, you can set the color of certain components with input variables, for example `<ion-navbar color="dark">` or `<ion-item color="dark">`.

I've tried this kind of input on `ion-content` but without any success. I could set `background-color` manually, for example `style="background-color:#ddd;"`, but if there is a 'proper' way to do this in Ionic I would rather do that instead. What is the 'official' way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official way of doing this. Ionic does not provide any `attribute or API` to change the background color of `ion-content` directly.

You will have to go through setting up the css yourself.

Just eg:

In your scss file :

```
.bg-style {
    background: red;
}
```

and apply style to content as in your component Html file :

```
<ion-content class="bg-style">
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **app.scss** add:

```
.content {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In **.scss** file, you can try with:

```
ion-content { background-color: map-get($colors, dark) !important; }
```